# Python grequests issue

Tags: python, python-requests, sdn, grequests

I am trying to make calls to several URLs at the same time using the grequests library for Python. The problem is that I do not quite understand the logic of grequests. Below is a sample (edited version) of my code:-

```
respArray = []
response = []
sessionvar = requests.Session()
sessionvar.trust_env = False
for each in range(0,len(urls)):
        response.append(grequests.get(urls[each],session=sessionvar,cookies=cookiesArray[each]))
        eachresp = grequests.map(response)
 for r in eachresp:
    respArray.append(r.json())

return respArray
```

My `respArray` returns each individual array which was returned from the URLs.
When I run that array, it's as if each one is running on its own loop, and not concurrently. I am not getting how can I get it to run concurrently so that I get faster results.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
for each in range(0,len(urls)):
        response.append(grequests.get(urls[each],session=sessionvar,cookies=cookiesArray[each]))
        eachresp = grequests.map(response)
 for r in eachresp:
    respArray.append(r.json())
```

Is effectively sending each request sequentially. You send the url and wait for grequests to send it in *each* loop iteration.

Basically it looks like:

- Loop iteration, wait for request
- Loop iteration, wait for request

etc.

You need to follow how [their documentation suggests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests#usage):

```
# Build a list of unsent requests
requests = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)
# Send them all at once
results = grequests.map(requests)
return [r.json() for r in results]
```

This will build your list of unsent requests and *then* send them all together. In other words:

- Loop iteration, create unsent request
- Loop iteration, create unsent request
- ...
- Send *all* requests simultaneously

Comment: I actually need to pass cookies which acts as a token to retrieve data .. What i am looking for is to use r.json() sequentially to call something deeper in the xml structure of each of the urls..

Comment: r.json() gives me all of the responses together.. How could I use each of them to make a call parallely to something deeper in each of the urls? That way it would make my search criteria faster.